# Cryptic Bash command ... purports to log the whole script's execution

Tags: bash, unix, scripting

I have some code handed from someone long gone to another department. It purports to log everything to the $MBL location, however, it does not; it creates an empty file in the $MBL location :-(

`exec > >(tee ${MBL}) 2>&1`

I can tell that it takes stderr and sends it to stdout; I can tell that tee should output the result to stdout and to $MBL. However, I don't understand the `exec > >()` syntax.

Reading the bash(1) man page suggests that a fork happens....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things going on here:  `exec` with only redirections redirects the shell's own file descriptors, and the `>(command)` syntax in `bash` and `zsh` creates a pipe and substitutes a `/dev/fd/*` reference to its input.

As written, this looks like it does what it is claimed to do.. but there may be other redirections in the script, or if it's being run in a shell that doesn't support `>(command)` then it will spit out an error and do nothing useful.

Comment: Okay. Looks like the problem is that in the particular environment I am using, /dev/fd/*n* isn't created (...don't ask).  Accepting your answer since it explains what's going on.

Comment: If it's Linux then there should be a symlink `/dev/fd/` -> `/proc/self/fd/`.  Other environments will vary, and I suppose there are still systems out there that don't support the concept.

Comment: Yes, well, proc is empty in this Linux setup. It's pretty out there. =)